# requestContext update/execute... doesn't work when <h:head> is present

Tags: jsf, primefaces, liferay, portlet, requestcontext

I have a portlet deployed in liferay 6.2 (Tomcat 7.0.42).
I use Primefaces 4 and liferay bridge 3.2.4-ga5.

I am aware of this post:
[RequestContext won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212481/requestcontext-wont-work)
But I have a strange problem here:

Primefaces doesn't work without the h:head tags, but when I add them the site won't update when I send the data to the bean. According to the server log the fields get updated, the p:log will say that the DOM has been updated, but nothing happens on the site, unless I remove the h:head tags. In that case the site will update with the new data, but primefaces won't work/display properly.

I even tried this demo example 1:1:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/requestContext.xhtml

But the outcome is the same.

I'm not sure what might be causing this.

Any ideas?

Thanks&BR

Edit:

Ok, I just found out, that I need to add the namespace to the update method.
So in the case of portlets it's not enough to use update("form:obj"), but update("namespace:form:obj) ... that head tag thing is still kinda strange.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
context.update(":formId:panelId");
```

or

```
context.update(":panelId");
```